# Transparent menus

Tags: interface

I'm fairly new to Blender and I've discovered that the UI (specifically the menus) are transparent and it's making it difficult to use!

Can anyone help me turn this off?

[image: Transparent save menu]

[image: Transparent menu options]

Comment: This is the result of either an unsupported graphics card, or out of date graphics drivers (likely the former). Make sure you're drivers are up to date and look here for GPU compatibility - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/ If your GPU is unsupported, you can still use 2.79

Comment: Caused by drivers for the GPU or unsupported hardware.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett
That'll be it! I've got an older mac running 10.13 but the hardware is late 2009 so quite outdated! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. Like I said, you can still use 2.79 - the UI isn't as pretty and there's no EEVEE, but most of the features are still there.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the original question, the issue was likely with an outdated graphics driver. However, if anyone installed the latest version of Blender (2.93.1) and happened to reset things to the default (rather than using settings from a previous Blender version), you may notice that the side panels (toolbar, n-panel) are partially transparent.

This can be fixed by going to **Edit > Preferences > Interface > Editors**, and uncheck "**Region Overlap**". This will also prevent the 3D view from showing in the minimized sections of your sidebar.

However, if you don't mind the regions overlapping, but just don't want transparency, then go to **Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Panel Colors**, and change the alpha values for both "**Header**" and "**Background**" to **1** (from 0.902 and 0.941 respectively).