# Is it possible to fade a piece of Blender layout out using python code?

Tags: python, interface

I mean... is it possible to programmatically have a piece of layout in Blender fade out so the underling objects show thru?

[image]

I'd like to have a slider so I can see my object, without Blender UI parts getting in the way. I've checked around but I wasn't able to find any reference.
Thank you.

Comment: i don't think u can. i mean... i'd be surprised if that was possible.

Comment: You can set them in Preferences, but not programatically and it's a bit of a fiddle! See the last paragraph of the last answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203259/transparent-menus

Comment: So it's not possible with python, I'm afraid. Thank you the same, guys